# How to await a task from a command?

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous

I am trying to wait for the end of a task. This task loads a bunch of things from the server and usually takes about 2 to 3 seconds. This task is started by the command LoadItemsCommand. Once the task is over, it should check if anything has been loaded, and if any of the loaded items already contain values. If yes, it should remove a button from the Toolbar.

But it doesn't wait.
The command call and specifically ask to await the task, but on the main page, things procede without waiting for the end of the task. i tried to put a loop with 30 second wait time to wait for the command to work, but nothing.

Here is the command in the viewmodel:

```cs
LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
```

Here is the LoadItems Function in the ViewModel

```cs
async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;
    IsBusy = true;

    List<string> stockIds = new List<string>();
    foreach (var orderline in this._order)
    {
        stockIds.Add(orderline.StockId);
    }
    string[] array = new string[stockIds.Count];
    stockIds.CopyTo(array, 0);
    this._products = await Common.GetProducts(new ProductSearchFilter { StockId = array });

    _scanStart = Common.Now;
    Items.Clear();

    bool already_scanned = false; // Todo trouver un meilleur non car pas tres explicite

    foreach (PickingOrderLineToHandle orderLine in _order)
    {
        if (orderLine.ScannedQuantity < orderLine.Quantity)
        {
            if ((bool)orderLine.WasSentToEnd && !already_scanned)
            {
                Items.Add(new ListItem() { Name = " ----- ", Id = "-1" });
                already_scanned = true;
            }

            Product product = null;
            foreach (var prod in _products)
            {
                if (prod.StockId == orderLine.StockId)
                {
                    product = prod;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Items.Add(new ListItem() { Name = $"{(orderLine.Quantity - orderLine.ScannedQuantity).ToString()} / {orderLine.Quantity}\t + {orderLine.Table_bin.LabelAddress} {product.ProductName} {orderLine.stock.Platform}", Id = orderLine.StockId });
        }
    }

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

And here is the call in the page:

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);

    int loop = 0;
    while (viewModel.IsBusy && loop < 60)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        loop++;
    };

    if (loop == 60)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Erreur", "Une erreur est survenue lors du chargment. Veuillez réessayer.", "Ok");
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    var cantCancel = viewModel.Items.Any(i => i.BookedQuantity > 0);

    if (Common.IsTeamLeader)
        cantCancel = false;

    if (cantCancel)
    {
        var cancelButton = this.ToolbarItems.Where(b => b.Text == "Annuler").First();
        this.ToolbarItems.Remove(cancelButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the method signature of _And here is the call in the page:_

Comment: Try using `AsyncRelayCommand` instead of `Command`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.input.asyncrelaycommand-1?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.1

Comment: @MetroSmurf Added to the message. protected override void OnAppearing()

Comment: @ewerspej Didn't know about this package. I tried with it, and now it locks up inside the async function when I call Common.GetProducts(new ProductSearchFilter { StockId = array }). I can confirm that the server is getting the request and sending the answer.

Comment: Can't you just change the visibility of `ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()` to `public`? You would need to change the signature of the calling method to `protected override async void OnAppearing()` and inside that you could then do `await viewModel.ExecuteLoadItemsCommand();`. Regular `Command` instances do not `await` the executing method if it's an asynchronous method. `async void` methods always are executed in a *fire and forget* fashion and your lambda `async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()` is such a method, just as an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

The following statement seems like a blocking call, but actually, since the method that is called by the `Command` is an **asynchronous anonymous** function, it will just execute in a ***fire and forget*** fashion and will **not** be awaited:

```cs
viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
```

That's because of how the Command is defined:

```cs
LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
```

A `Command` like this always executes synchronously. However, when calling an `async void` method from within a synchronous context, it will just begin execution, but won't `await` the method (hence *fire and forget*).

## Solution

Now, the way you're using the `Command` is unusual. Normally, you would bind to the `Command` from a UI control or you would just trigger its execution. You are expecting it to finish ***before*** the rest of the code is executed, which isn't the case as I've explained above.

Instead of executing the Command like that, you could instead do the following:

1. Make sure `ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()` is returning a `Task`
2. Change the visibility of `ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()` to public
3. Change the name to `ExecuteLoadItemsAsync()` which is a common notation for methods that return asynchronous Tasks

Your new method signature should look something like this:

```cs
public async Task ExecuteLoadItemsAsync()
{
    //...
}
```

Then, in your page's code-behind, you could change the `OnAppearing()` method override to run asynchronously by adding the `async` keyword to the signature and then awaiting the `ExecuteLoadItemsAsync()` method:

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await viewModel.ExecuteLoadItemsAsync();

    //...
}
```

This way, you're executing and awaiting the method directly. The `Command` can still be used for any UI elements to bind to, such as buttons.

## Optional improvement

In your ViewModel, you could use an `AsyncRelayCommand` instead of `Command` like this:

```cs
private AsyncRelayCommand _loadItemsCommand;
public AsyncRelayCommand LoadItemsCommand => _loadItemsCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(ExecuteLoadItemsAsync);
```

However, this doesn't change the fact that you shouldn't execute the Command in your page's code behind the way you've been attempting.